# How to turn a integer into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have integer

```
n = 504
```

I want it to be a list like this

```
ls = [5, 0, 4]
```

How can I approach?
Here is my solution:

```
n = 504
tmpList = list(str(n))
ls = [int(i) for i in tmpList]
```

Any better way to do it?(probably a shorter way)

Comment: Perhaps `[int(i) for i in str(504)]`?

Comment: Didn't see that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[int(i) for i in str(504)]
```

Output:

```
[5,0,4]
```

Comment: This solution was already proposed by Chris in comment

Comment: Ok I did not see

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit overkill, but you could use `re.findall` here:

```
n = 504
parts = re.findall(r'\d', str(n))
print(parts)

['5', '0', '4']
```

Use `map` if you want a list of actual integers:

```
parts = results = map(int, parts)
print(parts)

[5, 0, 4]
```

Comment: Note that, I want the items inside the list to be integer not string.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With a while loop it could be:

```
num = 504
result = []

while num > 10:
  mod = num % 10
  num = num // 10
  result = [mod] + result

result = [num] + result


print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
n = 504
lst = list(map(int,str(n)))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[5,0,4]
```